# removing aptana ' and " auto completes

Tags: autocomplete, aptana, pydev

Is it possible in Aptana(PyDev) to only remove the autocomplete that completes the ' and "?

I was not able to find it in the preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to window preferences->PyDev->Editor->Typing uncheck Automatic literal closing

Found another one in window preferences->Aptana Studio->Editors near the top there's a checkbox Auto-close matching character pairs, I had to un-check that.